# Add incremental counter to string in rows of a dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to add a counter to  all "unknown" strings in the dataframe.
Here is the dataframe

```
structure(list(Phylum = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Acidobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Acidobacteria bacterium RIFCSPLOWO2_02_FULL_64_15", 
"Actinobacteria"), class = "factor"), Order = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Actinomycetales", "Corynebacteriales", 
"unknown"), class = "factor"), Family = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Actinomycetaceae", "Corynebacteriaceae", 
"unknown"), class = "factor"), Genus = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Corynebacterium", "Trueperella", "unknown"
), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "unknown", class = "factor"), Genecoverage = c(5.58715596330275, 
761.405303030303, 42.5656565656566, 91.910447761194, 63.1912223121422, 
87.9927983539095)), .Names = c("Phylum", "Class", "Order", "Family", 
"Genus", "Species", "Genecoverage"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

For the first row i would like to replace all "unknown" occurences with "unknown_1".
For the second row replace all "unknown" occurences with "unknown_2" and so on...

Can you help?

thanks

Comment: How about try `make.unique(as.character(df1$Species))`  Or for all columns `df1[] <-  lapply(df1, function(x) replace(as.character(x), x == "unknown", paste0(x[x=="unknown"], seq_len(sum(x == "unknown")))))`

Comment: The "unknown" string could be in any of the column, not just the species one.

Comment: That is the reason I updated my earlier comment.  Please check it

Comment: Thanks, I posted my comment as a solution to consider the numeric columns as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the non-numeric columns and `replace` the non-numeric columns 'unknown' by `paste`ing with the sequence values

```
i1 <- !sapply(df1, is.numeric)
df1[i1] <- lapply(df1[i1], function(x) factor(replace(as.character(x),
     x == "unknown", paste0(x[x=="unknown"], seq_len(sum(x == "unknown"))))))
df1
#         Phylum                                             Class             Order             Family           Genus  Species Genecoverage
#1  Acidobacteria Acidobacteria bacterium RIFCSPLOWO2_02_FULL_64_15          unknown1           unknown1        unknown1 unknown1     5.587156
#2 Actinobacteria                                    Actinobacteria   Actinomycetales   Actinomycetaceae     Trueperella unknown2   761.405303
#3 Actinobacteria                                    Actinobacteria Corynebacteriales Corynebacteriaceae Corynebacterium unknown3    42.565657
#4 Actinobacteria                                    Actinobacteria Corynebacteriales Corynebacteriaceae Corynebacterium unknown4    91.910448
#5 Actinobacteria                                    Actinobacteria Corynebacteriales Corynebacteriaceae Corynebacterium unknown5    63.191222
#6 Actinobacteria                                    Actinobacteria Corynebacteriales Corynebacteriaceae Corynebacterium unknown6    87.992798
```